# Finding the position of similar elements in a matrix

Tags: matrix

I want to find the position of the elements which are equal in a matrix. For example in the case of the following matrix:

$m =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & x \\
 x & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$

```
m = {{a, x}, {x, a}};
```

I want to get these two sets:

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}}
> ```

How can I do that? Is there a built in function?

Comment: You should provide a bigger matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a method that has far better computational complexity than `Position`:

```
f1[m_] := Cases[Last @ Reap @ MapIndexed[Sow[#2, #] &, m, {2}], {_, __}]
```

Test:

```
SeedRandom[0]
m = RandomInteger[5, {4, 4}];
m // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  5 & 1 & 0 & 4 \\
>  0 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\
>  1 & 0 & 3 & 3 \\
>  4 & 2 & 0 & 4
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
f1[m]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}},
>  {{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}},
>  {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 4}},
>  {{2, 4}, {4, 2}},
>  {{3, 3}, {3, 4}}}
> ```

Alternative code; it is slightly faster than `f1` in version 7, but might faster (or slower) in newer versions:

```
f2[m_] := Module[{x}, Cases[ArrayRules[m, x] ~GatherBy~ Last, {_, __}][[All, All, 1]] ];
```

---

To my consternation I tried the same method that rasher recently posted but I managed to lose the potential performance of that method.  My mistake was to use `Extract[m, #] &` instead of `m[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] &`.  I expected `Extract` to be at least as fast; I still don't know why it is not.  Nevertheless my revised `f3`:

```
f3[m_] := GatherBy[Tuples @ Range @ Dimensions @ m, m[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] &] ~Cases~ {_, __}
```

---

#### Timings

Comparative timings with Öskå's `pos`.  Timing function:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
```

On small arrays my functions are only a few times faster.  (`f3` is already much faster.)

```
m = RandomInteger[40, {15, 20}];
Scan[Print @ timeAvg @ #[m] &, {pos, f1, f2, f3}]
```

> 0.0005984
>   0.00020992
>   0.0002096
>   0.000089856

But as the array size and especially number of unique elements increases `pos` rapidly slows down:

```
m = RandomInteger[500, {40, 70}];
Scan[Print @ timeAvg @ #[m] &, {pos, f1, f2, f3}]
```

> 0.04744
>   0.0020464
>   0.0019968
>   0.000848

```
m = RandomInteger[3000, {120, 160}];
Scan[Print @ timeAvg @ #[m] &, {pos, f1, f2, f3}]
```

> 2.792
>   0.02372
>   0.02308
>   0.005872

```
m = RandomInteger[10000, {300, 400}];
Scan[Print @ timeAvg @ #[m] &, {pos, f1, f2, f3}]   (* warning: very slow! *)
```

> 122.991
>   0.2404
>   0.2404
>   0.04244

Comment: @rasher Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

How about that? I believe that you should provide a bigger example though.

```
m = {{a, x}, {x, a}}
pos[m_] := 
  Position[m, #] & /@ First /@ Select[Tally@Flatten@m, Last@# >= 2 &]
pos@m
```

> {{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 1}}}

```
SeedRandom@0;
mat = RandomChoice[Range@25, {5, 5}]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  21 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 23 \\
>  8 & 17 & 3 & 3 & 4 \\
>  20 & 2 & 25 & 11 & 22 \\
>  13 & 18 & 12 & 23 & 13 \\
>  19 & 22 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
pos@mat//Column
```

> ```
> {{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{5,4}}
> {{1,5},{4,4}}
> {{3,2},{5,3},{5,5}}
> {{3,5},{5,2}}
> {{4,1},{4,5}}
> ```

---

If one wants to illustrate their position in a colorful way:

```
SeedRandom@0;
mat /. (Rule[#, Style[#, RGBColor@RandomReal[{}, 3]]] & /@ (First /@ 
  Select[Tally@Flatten@mat, Last@# >= 2 &])) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. The first edition of your answer was fine. Why did you change that? What is the difference?

Position[m, #] & /@ First /@ Tally@Flatten@m

Comment: It's different if you have one single variable: `{{a,x},{b,a}}` where only `a` is repeated. With the first version you would have the position of `x` and `b` while they are not repeated, with this one you only have the position of the elements repeated at least twice.

Comment: Öskå, be aware that repeated use of `Position` can be very slow.  Please see my answer for an alternative and timing examples.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well well well.., 122 seconds is quite long indeed.. :) I should really get into `Reap/Sow`.

Answer (score 4):

About 10X faster than fastest so far posted using `timeAvg` from above...

```
fr= With[{a = Flatten[Array[List, Dimensions@#], 1], l = #},GatherBy[a, l[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] &]] &
```

Quick test of the fastest using `timeAvg` with data generated as `m = RandomInteger[size, {size, size}]`, with the usual loungebook caveats... I did not include `Position` based solution, as Mr. Wizard noted it explodes time-wise with larger problems.

[image]

Addressing *RunnyKine*'s comment re: singlets (I chose to include them, since OP does not specify treatment of these precisely), and switching *Kguler*'s to his fixed version:

```
frX=Cases[With[{a = Flatten[Array[List, Dimensions@#], 1], l = #}, 
                GatherBy[a, l[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] &]], {_, __}] &
```

[image]

No material difference in timings (`fr` and `frX` lie on top of each other here, average difference in time treating singlets per comment is <5%)...

Comment: @RunnyKine: since the OP does not specify precisely what "same" is, a bit irrelevant, clearly a singlet is the same as itself.. Nonetheless, simply adding `Cases` to filter that still results in only ~10% overhead, so still vastly faster. I'll update plot to reflect this.

Comment: Very strange.  I actually tried what I thought was very similar to this and it wasn't faster.  However I can confirm that this is.  I wish I had that old code to compare because I'd really like to know what I did wrong to kill the potential of this method! +1 of course.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  Can you explain why `Extract` was slow here?

Comment: By the way, for future timing graphs I highly recommend using LogPlot -- it makes it much easier to see the order of complexity.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Re: why you saw slower -  perhaps you applied `Sequence` to the position pair to get the index? I've found doing so, vs directly addressing the sub-elements to get the indices, is much slower (but more flexible). Beats me why, and the same for `Extract`... I've learned (and had it reinforced by seeing some of your solutions) to try different things, however outlandish they might seem. Would be nice to know the "why", but with the opaqueness of the system, probably not much hope there.

Comment: After some consideration I guess `m[[ #[[1]], #[[2]] ]] &` can be compiled since the depth of extraction is explicit, whereas `Extract[m, #] &` cannot be.  I really hate having to use the long form however.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using the new-in-version-10 [`PositionIndex`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PositionIndex.html) function.

```
f4[m_] :=
  m // Flatten // PositionIndex // Values // Cases[{_, __}] //
    (1 + IntegerDigits[# - 1, Length @ First @ m, 2] &)
```

Test:

```
SeedRandom[0]
m = RandomInteger[5, {4, 4}];

f4[m]
```

> ```
> {
>  {{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}},
>  {{1, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}},
>  {{1, 4}, {2, 2}, {4, 1}, {4, 4}},
>  {{2, 4}, {4, 2}},
>  {{3, 3}, {3, 4}}
> }
> ```

This is not as fast as my earlier `f3` but I think it is an interesting variation, hopefully worthy of posting.