# How to select a submatrix containing similar elements from a matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

( This question is related but does not ( fully ) answer my questions. - [Finding the position of similar elements in a matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50578/finding-the-position-of-similar-elements-in-a-matrix) )

I have not written code yet, I am in the design phase of code for the following problem. I will illustrate the problem with a 6-by-6 matrix in the form of inputs and expected outputs and a commentary. In practice the matrices will be in the order of 2000 by 2000 ( if a solution is realistic ).

I want to scan a matrix for blocks ( rows, columns, submatrix ) containing similar elements ( in this particular case: equal elements ). When such a block is found I want to know:
1) topleft index
2) bottom right index
3) submatrix of elements
4) the matrix with similar elements set to Null

Input:

```
 {
   {1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6},
   {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3},
   {1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9},
   {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
   {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
   {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}} // MatrixForm
```

Output:

```
 {{1,1},{3,1}}     (* top left , bottom right indices*)
 {{1},{1},{1}}     (* sub matrix *)

 {{1,2},{3,2}}     
 {{2},{2},{2}}

 {{1,3},{3,3}}     
 {{1},{1},{1}}

 {{2,3},{2,4}}     
 {{1, 1}}

 {{4,1},{6,6}}     
 {
   {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
   {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4},
   {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}}


  (* what remains of the matrix with similar elements Nulled *)
 {  
  {Null, Null, Null, 4, 5, 6},
  {Null, Null, Null, Null, 2, 3},
  {Null, Null, Null, 7, 8, 9},
  {Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null},
  {Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null},
  {Null, Null, Null, Null, Null, Null}} // MatrixForm
```

Question: I am basically interested in how to select a submatrix with similar elements, in the form of a code snippet, **a clear explanation of the code**, why this particular method was chosen and if you are aware of any other methods that could be tried to give the same result.

Note: Similarity of elements in this case is that two elements in a row or column are equal, but this should not be hardcoded a pure function should be provided to explain what similarity means, although the default case could be set to the above example.

This example :

```
 {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
  {1, 1, 1, 2, 2},
  {1, 1, 1, 2, 2}}
```

seems to have multiple solutions. It does not really matter which one to choose as long as no doubles remain in the final matrix. So a 4x3 with 1s and a 2x2 and a 2x2 with 2swith 1s is ok but also a 2x5 with 1s and a 2x3 with 1s and a 2x2 with 2s is ok.

Comment: How do you want to handle conflicts? Say, a `T`-shaped patch of similar elements, as in `{{1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}`?

Comment: There is a conflict in the example. Report both. Report horizontal and vertical.

Comment: I don't have time right now to write an answer, but I think a good direction would be to use [`ClusteringComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClusteringComponents.html) for the "segmentation", and then use that to find the maximal rectangles that one can fit in each component.

Comment: Entirely new function to me. I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: What about conflicting submatrix blocks of the form `{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
  {1, 1, 1, 2, 2},
  {1, 1, 1, 2, 2}} // MatrixForm`? Should both the submatrices be returned but not the single rows/columns?

Comment: Also, what about a matrix of the form `{{1, 1, 1},
  {2, 1, 1},
  {3, 4, 5}}`? Should in this case be returned a row and a 2x2 submatrix?

Comment: It does not really matter as long as no doubles remain in the final matrix. So regarding the first a 4x3 with 1s and a 2x2 and a 2x2 with 2swith 1s is ok but also a 2x5 with 1s and a 2x3 with 1s and a 2x2 with 2s is ok.

Comment: Second example could be a 1x3 with 1s and a 1x2 with 1s. Leaving the 1 in the final matrix would not be correct.

Comment: That was a good question @glance. I added it to the original question above.

Comment: What have *you* done/tried? I don't see a real question here, just a specification for "do my work for me...".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a work order and not a question regarding some particular difficulty or problem using Mathematica.

Comment: @ciao I am working on the route as described in the related question. I would be happy with a hint in the right direction. I only post questions here after serious attempts. Don't know where you live, but it is almost bedtime won't be able to work on it for 18 hours.

Comment: @ndroock1: This is an np-hard problem (first shown by Mathies IIRC in the eighties). There's a fine book called "Pattern Matching Algorithms" by Galil that covers common submatrix matching, perhaps you can find a copy in a local Uni library?

Comment: Thanks @ciao. Now I have got something to work on.

Comment: @Ciao I got a copy of the book. Will read it tomorrow, I assume you mean the Chapter on Two Dimensional Matching, right?

Comment: @ndroock1: Might be - I'm not at my home with my library so can't check (but glad to see I recalled the author correctly - if it's a book with a collection by a bunch of authors, with Galil as editor - that's it). As an aside, there might be some sorcery you could do using MMA's image processing functions to aid searching (they handle masking/etc), but for the sizes your hinting at, might be better served using C/something parallel/Cuda etc...

Comment: @ciao - The thing is that the answer in the related question comes awfully close! And that is only a Mma one-liner. - I will get back on this, later.

Comment: To clarify my closing vote, I believe asking **a clear explanation of the code** in bold means you want the hard work made by anyone else, when it should be on **you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt. It most probably won't do for large matrices due to the inefficient algorithm, but it seems to work on smaller examples:

```
enlargeBlock[matrix_List, blockStart_List, blockEnd_List] := Which[
  (* enlarge in the down-right-diagonal direction, if possible *)
  And @@ Thread[blockEnd < Dimensions@matrix] &&
   matrix[[blockStart[[1]] ;; blockEnd[[1]] + 1, 
     blockStart[[2]] ;; blockEnd[[2]] + 1]] == 
    ConstantArray[matrix[[Sequence @@ blockStart]], 
     blockEnd - blockStart + 2],
  blockEnd + 1,
  (* enlarge in the down-vertical direction, if possible *)
  blockEnd[[1]] < First@Dimensions@matrix &&
   matrix[[blockStart[[1]] ;; blockEnd[[1]] + 1, 
     blockStart[[2]] ;; blockEnd[[2]]]] == 
    ConstantArray[
     matrix[[Sequence @@ blockStart]], {blockEnd[[1]] - 
       blockStart[[1]] + 2, blockEnd[[2]] - blockStart[[2]] + 1}],
  {blockEnd[[1]] + 1, blockEnd[[2]]},
  (* enlarge in the right-horizontal direction, if possible *)
  blockEnd[[2]] < Last@Dimensions@matrix &&
   matrix[[blockStart[[1]] ;; blockEnd[[1]], 
     blockStart[[2]] ;; blockEnd[[2]] + 1]] == 
    ConstantArray[
     matrix[[Sequence @@ blockStart]], {blockEnd[[1]] - 
       blockStart[[1]] + 1, blockEnd[[2]] - blockStart[[2]] + 2}],
  {blockEnd[[1]], blockEnd[[2]] + 1},
  True,
  blockEnd
  ]
findBiggestBlock[matrix_List, blockStart_List] := 
 FixedPoint[enlargeBlock[matrix, blockStart, #] &, blockStart]
findBlocks[matrix_List] := 
 Block[{mask = ConstantArray[1, Dimensions@matrix]},
     Do[
      If[mask[[i, j]] == 1,
       With[{blockEnd = findBiggestBlock[matrix, {i, j}]},
        Sow@
         Association[start -> {i, j}, end -> blockEnd, 
          elements -> 
           matrix[[i ;; blockEnd[[1]], j ;; blockEnd[[2]]]]];
        mask[[i ;; blockEnd[[1]], j ;; blockEnd[[2]]]] = 0
        ]
       ],
      {i, First@Dimensions@matrix},
      {j, Last@Dimensions@matrix}
      ]
     ] // Reap // Last // Last
```

And as an usage example:

```
(m = {{1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 1, 7, 8, 9}, {4, 
     4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
     4}}) // MatrixForm
findBlocks[m]
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, - Knuth allegedly said that optimization comes last. This is a start! Please read the comment section about what @ciao said about the problem. I will work on this again this evening UTC+1.

Comment: Also: This ( I referred to it in the question ) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50578/finding-the-position-of-similar-elements-in-a-matrix has a solution that comes very, very close and is compact.

Comment: @ndroock1 I saw that post, but I don't think it's very similar to this problem. The hard thing here is to find elements which are "similar" *and* close.  It's the last constraint that forces the use of more elaborated code (and way more computational time).